# There are $N$ chess players of different strengths. If two of them play, the stronger one always wins.

Tags: combinatorics

What is the minimum number of games they need to play for us to determine the order of their strengths?

I was asked this question for $N=5$ and I got 5 rounds, but I'm not sure how to generalize it to any $N$. Thanks for any help.

Comment: Essentially, you are asking for the minimum number of comparisons required to sort a list with $N$ elements ([Wikipedia reference](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comparison_sort#Number_of_comparisons_required_to_sort_a_list)).

Comment: Wow! Did not think of that. Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think for $N = 5$, it may be 7 rounds because $2^6 < 5! < 2^7$. In other words there are 120 permutations of order of player strengths and each comparison reduces the size by half.

Comment: It can be expressed as $\lceil log_2{n!} \rceil$.

Answer (score 0):

See [Sorting numbers: minimal number of comparisons needed to sort n elements](https://oeis.org/A036604) for the calculated solutions for $n=1,2,\ldots,15$, and yes 5 items need 7 comparisons.